# Resolve stimulsoft Problems

Tags: stimulsoft

I want to calculate the creditor and debtor amounts for each currency and show them at the bottom of the table, but no matter how much I searched, nothing was found. Can anyone help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OK5s.png)

Answer (score 0):

1- You can use summary of text box in footer band or footer page
[image]
2- You can use expression of text box in footer band or footer page

[image]